# Firebase AuthResult on task shows cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Getting red line over Task. I have imported `import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;` too, yet it shows `cannot resolve symbol authresult` in that too.

```
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    sign_up_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);    
    sign_up_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email_a = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String password_a = password.getText().toString().trim();
            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_a, password_a)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterStaff.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterStaff.this, "Registration Complete..:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterStaff.this, "Registration failed..." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterStaff.this, StaffLogin.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    }
             );}
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Did you add the google repository from the SDK Manager ? Is Android Studio higher than 1.5 ? Did you add firebase to the gradle dependencies ? Can you post more information here ?

Comment: Yes i've added all gradle dependencies. And my studio version is 2.2.2. google repository is also there.

Comment: Okay... did you try to clean and compile and build once again ? Android Studio restart ? Also, if possible post the actual error...

Comment: Yea.. I tried multiple times.. Still it persists.. The actual error is that,  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task), in this, AuthResult is showing cannot find symbol error.

Comment: Cleared it. I have used 9.0.2 for auth for 9.6.1 for other dependencies. Now after changing it to 9.6.1, it's working. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 5):

make sure you compile the same version of authresult as core like :-

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

all are same 10.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Change your version of firebase for the latest, this worked for me in flutter adding in pubspec.yml

```
firebase_auth: ^0.15.0+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions which might help :

1)  add the google repository from the SDK Manager.

2) Per requirements for FireBase, Android Studio should be higher than 1.5

3) Gradle dependencies for FireBase must be correct and consistent.

4) Clean and Build and build once again with/without Android Studio restart.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this version in your Dependecy. I faced this problem too. but finally solved this by adding :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below listed in app gradle and then sync

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
```

Comment: Please, improve the code blocks and give a description about what you are proposing for a better understanding of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please add

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1

at build.gradle and try to recompile again.

I had used the below code snipped for creating user id and password

```
    FirebaseUser currentUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser ==null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,FirebaseAuthActivity.class));
        finish();
        return;

    }

    TextView email=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    TextView displayName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayName);

    email.setText(currentUser.getEmail());
    displayName.setText(currentUser.getDisplayName());
```

Answer (score 0):

make the changes to this file build.gradle(Module: app)

You can solve this by providing the latest version possible for each package.

NOTE: they do not all need to be the same...mine for example goes like this...

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
```

when done editing the file, click on sync gradle. And as at this time of writing, i am using android studio 3.1.3, and when you sync, the lint will let you know if there's a newer version, you can simply make changes to the version numbers and sync again.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Dependency Ver :9.6.1 for all firebase packages.

Then in my class I have included the following import:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
```

After Gradle Sync, the 'AuthResult' is no longer highlighted RED

Answer (score -1):

Try full path of package com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult instead of AuthResult.

why? I can't explain. It worked for me.